# Why Vanilla/jQuery redirected URL inside a iframe is decoded/encoded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

From a backend API I get an URL like this `http://example.com/thispage.html` and different parameters `lang=fr` and `reference=%2BParam`

the Form (**inside an iframe**) looks like :

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="http://example.com/thispage.html">
   <input name="lang" value="fr" type="hidden" />
   <input name="reference" value="%2BParam" type="hidden"/>
   ...
</form>
```

the JavaScript file looks like :

```
$("#myform").submit();
```

When the form is submitted, the url is not as expected. It's looks like :

```
http://example.com/thispage.html?lang=fr&reference=%252BParam
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/thispage.html?lang=fr&reference=%2BParam
```

Why is the redirection of the form inside the iframe failed and the parameter is encoded while redirecting?

Comment: Because you don't usually have encoded characters in an unencoded string. JQuery (or maybe the browser, not sure) likely just encodes any URL you give it. Otherwise what happens if you have non-URL characters there?

Comment: Yeah, like référence :)

Comment: If the form is really sent as a POST request then the parameter should not be sent in the URL at all.

Comment: the browser is not looking for already-encoded data within your string, it just encoded what you give it. If it's already encoded, it re-encodes it. That's not the browser's problem, it's your application's problem. The idea of forms originally was to capture user data, and users don't generally input encoded data. It's not something the browser's encoding system is designed to deal with. But, as max says, your form is supposedly submitted by POST. So you shouldn't have any URL parameters anyway. Not that it matters though because the POST vars would get encoded the same way.

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should manually decode the parameters from the original URL before you add them to your form fields.

Comment: Disclaimer: the form is inside an Iframe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The iFrame change the url while redirecting from POST. The solution for me was to redirect outside of the iFrame :

```
window.open(urlToBeRedirect);
```